# Suitescript fieldChanges location field

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0, clientscript

I'm still learning in netsuite. and I have a case like the following

on the Requisition form, if input requestor in requisiton, how to change location field automatically. we can get the location in the employee field

[image: Requisition]

[image: employee field]

can show an  simple code for this case, thank's for helping

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to go for a UserEvent script and use the beforeLoad hook instead to set the default values.

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define(["N/runtime"], function (runtime) {

    function beforeLoad(context) {
        var type = context.type
        var UserEventType = context.UserEventType;
        var newRecord = context.newRecord
        
        if (type != UserEventType.CREATE) return;
        
        var user = runtime.getCurrentUser()
        newRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'subsidiary', value: user.subsidiary });
        newRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'location', value: user.location });
        
    };

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    }

});
```

If you do want to use the `fieldChanged` in the client script and search for the location of the employee, your client script will need permissions on the employee record.

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(["N/search"], function (search) {

    function fieldChanged(context) {
        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord
        var fieldId = context.fieldId

        if (fieldId != 'entity') return
        
        const id = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: fieldId })
        if (!id) return
        
        search.lookupFields.promise({
            type : search.Type.EMPLOYEE,
            id : id,
            columns : [ 'subsidiary', 'location' ]
        }).then(function(user) {
            currentRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'subsidiary', value: user.subsidiary });
            currentRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'location', value: user.location });
        });
    }

    return {
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged
    }

});
```

Comment: thank's for that learn about 2 method this case. But if use `fieldChanged` can explain me about permissions on the employee record

Comment: If the role of the user who's executing has no permissions on the employee record, you could expose a Suitelet API (with a deployment with `execute as admin` as checked) and just do an http request to that endpoint to get the data.